# Using the Step Builder pattern for the creation of a complex object that contains an instance variable that is a list

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Let's say I want to construct an instance of the following object:

```
private class ComplexObject {
    private int param1; // Required Parameter
    private int param2; // Required Parameter
    private int param3; // Required Parameter
    private List<Integer> listParam4; // This list should contain atleast one Integer

    private ComplexObject() {
        this.listParam4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use the Step Builder pattern to construct this object, so that a user sets the value of the parameters in order. The main problem that I'm facing is with creating an interface for the last step. I want to expose the `build()` method after the user has provided atleast one integer that I can add in `listParam4`. At the same time I also want to give the user the option of providing more integers to add to the list before calling the `build()` method. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me a way of doing this or suggest an alternative approach in case I'm approaching this problem incorrectly.

Here is the code that I currently have to achieve this:

```
public interface SetParam1Step {
    SetParam2Step setParam1(int param1);
}

public interface SetParam2Step {
    SetParam3Step setParam2(int param2);
}

public interface SetParam3Step {
    AddToParam4ListStep setParam3(int param3);
}

public interface AddToParam4ListStep {
    // Not sure how to create this interface
}

public static class ComplexObjectBuilder implements SetParam1Step, SetParam2Step, SetParam3Step, AddToParam4ListStep {
    private int param1;
    private int param2;
    private int param3;
    private List<Integer> listParam4;

    private ComplexObjectBuilder() { 
        // Prevent Instantiation
    }

    @Override
    public AddToParam4ListStep setParam3(int param3) {
        this.param3 = param3;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public SetParam3Step setParam2(int param2) {
        this.param2 = param2;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public SetParam2Step setParam1(int param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        return this;
    }

    // Needs to implement the build() method and the methods that would eventually be added to the AddToParam4ListStep interface.

    public static SetParam1Step newInstance() {
        return new ComplexObjectBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the builder pattern is to allow you to set whichever fields in whatever order you want. This kind of misses the point. Also, you seem to want to check at compile time whether the required properties are set. Can't you do it at runtime and throw an exception?

Comment: why on earth would you need those interfaces? Design patterns are meant to make issues that occur often solvable in a way that is easy to implement/read/maintain, creating all those interfaces kind of defeats the purpose and adds no aditional value.

Comment: Well, AddToParam4ListStep should simply have an add() method returning yet another interface (AddToParam4ListOrBuild) that would allow to add() more parameters (returning itself) and to build the final object.

Comment: @Sweeper it's Step Builder, not Builder, interfaces are necessary to achieve building order. Check this [link](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/step-builder), this example looks like your case :)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot for your comment! It solves my query. If possible, can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @MateuszR. Thanks a lot the link! I'll definitely refer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddToParam4ListStep` should simply have an `add()` method returning yet another interface (`AddToParam4ListOrBuild`) that would allow to `add()` more parameters (returning itself) and to build the final object:

```
public interface AddToParam4ListStep {
    AddToParam4ListOrBuild add(Integer toAdd);
}

public interface AddToParam4ListOrBuild {
    AddToParam4ListOrBuild add(Integer toAdd);
    ComplexObject build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also feel that the `AddToParam4ListOrBuild` interface could extend from `AddToParam4List` just to avoid re-declaring the same method again.